# Maximal size length of WebAPI response on ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpresponse, iis-express, webapi

One of my controller's action returns huge collection in JSON response and when I make a request toward this controller WebAPI don't return a response. So I have tested this action using breakpoint and collection is filled normally. At the end I am sure that this is a problem of WebApi since I have tested this controller's action through several clients(WPF and Postman) and each one just hangs on waiting for a response. I think that the obstacle is the response size of my WebAPI. My WebAPI runs on IIS Express

So I have two questions:

1). What is the maximal size length of WebAPI response on ASP.NET Core 3.0?
2). How to increase maximal size length of WebAPI response on ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Comment: The response should be buffered. When you execute this request through browser do you see that request is pending state or completed. If pending, leave it and when it gets completed.  so even if you increase the max size then I don't think your problem is going to resolve. I would suggest to go for paging approach to return the data from API.

Comment: Hello @user1672994. When I do request through any client even browser it stops on pending state and don't become completed so I cannot receive the response. Any ideas?

Comment: @AllaevBekzod my idea is to try responding a smaller piece of data first to see if you could actually get a response. If you have no control over the server-side code (for debugging), you go out of luck.

Comment: Hello @KingKing. I wait for collection of order details(I use Northwind database). Order details model have two navigation properties. So I have tried another approach I have included only one navigation property. When I did this I received a response but when I included two navigation properties things I have described above happened. So at the end yes, I actually getting a response. What do you think about this?

Comment: @AllaevBekzod requesting from outside may have some interrupt (some kind of disconnection) so to get the most reliable insight into it, you can debug the code on the server side directly. I mean you can set some break points at the start & end of your service/api call and wait it there (to go from the first break point to the second one). If it seems to take forever, that's your server-code problem (not involve the max length configuring yet).

Comment: @KingKing I have debugged my server-side code. Result was like this even if include two navigational properties collection is filled normally and as result I have collection of all order details where two navigational properties are also loaded. But when action returns this collection I don't going back into my client.

Comment: @AllaevBekzod so how long does it take? (compared to what you have to wait for from the client side)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227481/discussion-between-allaev-bekzod-and-king-king).

Answer (score 10):

I came here looking for a solution to the same problem, but for me it was not resolved by changing the MaxResponseBufferSize.

As it turned out, it seems that Postman also returns this same error, as the maximum size can be configured, and the default is 50Mb.

In the Postman application, you can go to settings, and configure this to be 0 (unlimited), or whatever value you need.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 6 & 7 you can set the response buffer by having this line of code in `Program.cs` before calling the `builder.Build();` method

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = null;
});
```

By setting the `MaxResponseBufferSize` to `null`, the size of the response buffer is unlimited as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxresponsebuffersize?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation. Deafult Response buffer size is 64KB. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxresponsebuffersize?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

You can change it like:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureKestrel(x => x.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = yourSize)
          .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Looks like it is max length if run my WebAPI on Kestrel. What code should I wright if I run my WebAPI on IIS Express?
P.S. Sorry for not mentioning that I run my WebAPI on IIS Express, I will edit question)