# .NET Core - Increase Http web api response limit

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an API that returns a large number of data in a list.
when I am calling the API from postman I can't see the response.
i seen some solutions on google but in that they are setting
maxContentLength in web.config file.
but i haven't web.config file i have project in .net core (5.0)
There is anything that I need to do to increase API response?
here in this screenshot while debugging I can see the response.
[image]
[image]

here is the code :

```
  [HttpPost]
        [Route("ReconcileUpload")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 268435456)]  
        [RequestSizeLimit(52428800)]
        [hasAccess("OPRT_TXN")]
        public ReconcileResponse ReconcileUpload([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromQuery] BankChallanType FileType)
        {
            ReconcileResponse response = new ReconcileResponse();
            string storePath = "";
            using (var session = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
        //response filling
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    session.Rollback();
                    Logger.Error($"Error in {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} {e.Message} at {e.StackTrace}");
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storePath))
                        System.IO.File.Delete(storePath);
                }
                var x= response;
                return x;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "when I am calling the API from postman I can't see the response." Hi @BhavinVarsur, Can you explain more detail about can't see the API response from the postman, the request is successful or not and is there any error message? In the debug mode, try to set a break point in the API method, then when you call the API from the postman, check whether the API method is executed and return the data. Besides, you can also try to return a small amount of data to check if the API is working properly (using postman).

Comment: According to your code, I create a sample with a small amount of data and without the `[hasAccess("OPRT_TXN")]` attribute, it seems that everything works well. So you can try to remove the `[hasAccess("OPRT_TXN")]` attribute. If still not working, please explain more detail about the `hasaccess` attribute. Besides, since this thread has closed, you can try to reopen it or create a new thread with the detail information (or share the sample via github), then other community member will join it and give some help.

Comment: hasAccess is custom class that is performing validation of  permission. and i tried with return small amount of data and i got that small amount data in response but all the data not coming in response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771662/maximal-size-length-of-webapi-response-on-asp-net-core-3-0